# Plesk forbidden 403 getting bootstrap style (nginx)

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, plesk, httpforbiddenhandler

I have PLESK installed in my host and I create a subdomain "app.mysite.com". In this subdomain, I upload my codeigniter proyect with this structure:

[image]

When I try to access "css" folder to get boostrap.min.css file (app.mysite.com/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css), I get this forbidden error:
[image]

This is the additional directives for HTTP of this site:
[image]

And this other one is for HTTPS:
[image]

This website, redirect automatically from HTTP to HTTPS.

To finish, I add this code to additional nginx directives:
[image]

**Other test**

I try changing "additional nginx directive", to remove index.php from the URL:
[image]

But no style files are loaded and codeigniter read the url as controller call returning "404 page not found":

[image]

Please, I need help with this issue and how to configure correctly nginx to access css/, js/ and img/ folders files.
Thank you

**/EDIT**

I find the nginx.conf file of app.mysite.com subdomain:

```
    #ATTENTION!
    #
    #DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
    #SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

    server {
            listen 206.189.5.184:443 ssl http2;

            server_name app.mysite.com;
            server_name www.app.mysite.com;
            server_name ipv4.app.mysite.com;

            ssl_certificate             /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfMQnEev;
            ssl_certificate_key         /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfMQnEev;
            ssl_client_certificate      /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfcJsJQ3;

            client_max_body_size 128m;

            root "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/app.mysite.com";
            access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
            error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

            location / {
                    proxy_pass https://206.189.5.184:7081;
                    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    access_log off;

            }

            location ~ ^/(plesk-stat|awstats-icon|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat) {
                    proxy_pass https://206.189.5.184:7081;
                    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    access_log off;

            }
            location @fallback {
                    proxy_pass https://206.189.5.184:7081;
                    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    access_log off;

            }

            location ~ ^/(.*\.(ac3|avi|bmp|bz2|css|cue|dat|doc|docx|dts|eot|exe|flv|gif|gz|htm|html|ico|img|iso|jpeg|jpg|js|mkv|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|qt|ra$
                    try_files $uri @fallback;
            }

            location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
                    alias /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/web_users/$1/$2;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/php-fpm.sock";
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

            }

            location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
                    proxy_pass https://206.189.5.184:7081;
                    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    access_log off;

            }

            location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/php-fpm.sock";
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

            }
            location ~ /$ {
                    index "index.html" "index.cgi" "index.pl" "index.php" "index.xhtml" "index.htm" "index.shtml";
            }

            add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;

            include "/var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
    }

    server {
            listen 206.189.5.184:80;

            server_name app.mysite.com;
            server_name www.app.mysite.com;
            server_name ipv4.app.mysite.com;

            client_max_body_size 128m;

            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

Comment: Please share your nginx.conf first

Comment: @AlexC  I add the nginx.conf file content of this subdomain.

Comment: What is in the log files when you have 403 and 404 errors.
/var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/logs/proxy_error_log
/var/www/vhosts/system/app.mysite.com/logs/error_log